# What widget to use to get a sign up button with google logo at the left

Tags: flutter, dart

I saved the google logo a as .png because I want to keep its colors. I am aware there are some packages for predefined sign-in buttons like google or with the google Icon(but I can't keep the colors obviously in this case), but I would like to know if I can somehow make so the .png image acts like an Icon.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use whatever button widget you like or you can create your custom button...

According to your image you can use outline button or flat button... then in your child parameter add Row with image and text

```
OutlineButton(child: Row(children: Image.asset(your_image_location), Text('Sign in with Google')))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: IconButton(
                  icon: Image.asset('path/the_image.png'),
                  iconSize: 50,
                  onPressed: () {},
                )
            Positioned(
                child: Container(
              child: Center(child: Text('Sign in With Google')),
            )),
          ],
        )
```